# How to resolve the pipe character "|" not typing in in Xcode text editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Since 3 years developping iPhone apps, I used to type "|" characters using "Alt + Shift + L" shortcut. (French AZERTY layout)
Since yesterday this doesn't work anymore in Xcode (no problem in other text editors on the same Mac).
Any clue on how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Doesn't your keyboard have |\ key?

Comment: Nope, I've got a french AZERTY layout, anyway I found a solution, thank's for your concern.

Comment: In `XCode/Preferences/Key Bindings` check the shortcuts, one of them may cause a conflict (since it's only on XCode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there, done that. I'd suggest [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to customize your own keyboard layout, and for example make the `|` and `~` keys more accessible (for non-French people here, the tilde is on Alt+N on a French AZERTY keyboard, which is a pain).

For example, you could remap the `§` key (found on the key for `6`), which is absolutely useless in everyday use, to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to an Xcode plugin using the same shortcut as the pipe one.
Uninstalling this plugin solved it !